# Electron-mksnapshot snapshotResult.setGlobals location?

Tags: electron, v8, snapshot

I've created a script using electron-link. Within the links are basic requires needed for electron i.e:

```
function get_app() {
         return app = app || require("./node_modules/electron/index.js").app;
}
```

when running the script through electron I get the below error:
"To use Node's require you need to call `snapshotResult.setGlobals` first!"

I've attempted to add this line to many areas without much affect. is there a correct area to place this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I needed to wrap my main.js file in a function and export that function. then I can call the function after calling the .setGlobals function.